# Correct use of Single with control flow in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following Rx chain in my code:

```
public Single<List<Items>> dispatchStuff(){
    return mRepository.getList()
        .filter(list -> list.size() != 0)
        .flatMapSingle(mRepository::operateOnList())
        .doOnSuccess(mRepository::deleteList())
        .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
        .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui());
}
```

However, I'm not sure I'm using the filtering correctly here. The `getList()` method will always return a value or error, therefore I think using `Single` is acceptable. However, then I want to perform other operations only if there are elements in the list returned. If I filter `Single` and my list size is 0, it will through an exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFlatMapSingle$FlatMapMaybeObserver.onComplete(MaybeFlatMapSingle.java:106)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFilterSingle$FilterMaybeObserver.onSuccess(MaybeFilterSingle.java:92)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:37)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2692)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFilterSingle.subscribeActual(MaybeFilterSingle.java:40)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:3707)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFlatMapSingle.subscribeActual(MaybeFlatMapSingle.java:47)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2692)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2692)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:138)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)                                                                                                  
   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)                                                                                                  
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)                                                                                                  
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)                                                                                                  
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)                                                                                                  
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)                                                                                                  
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How should I correctly implement this control flow when I'm working with `Single`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's no longer a `Single`, it's a `Maybe`. If however you don't want to switch to Maybe, perhaps this will help:

```
public Single<List<Items>> dispatchStuff(){
  return mRepository.getList()
    .flatMapSingle(list ->
        list.size() > 0
        ? mRepository.operateOnList(list)
          .doOnSuccess(mRepository::deleteList)
        : Single.just(list)
    )
    .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
    .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui());
}
```

However, perhaps instead of a `Single<List<Items>>` you should actually have a `Flowable<Items>`?